# Drive a Latching Relay with AC Coil from ESP8266

Tags: ac, relay, esp8266

I have a couple of latching relays that uses AC coils (120 VAC, [Finder 20.22.8.120](https://www.finder-relais.net/en/finder-relays-series-20.pdf)) and I would like to control from a logic level DC circuit (GPIO from an ESP8266).

The relay´s datasheet states that in order to control it a 100ms pulse is needed(A1-A2) and that the coil consumes 54mA.

I tried to control it using a MOC3021 in a simple crude test circuit (I did not have the zero cross version at hand) but I destroyed two of them already on the first run (I did not add a snubber circuit in my tests).

[image: crude test circuit]

Would I really need add a triac here for such a small current and a short pulse to latch the relay? What did I do wrong in my test? Any suggestions on a possible circuit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Would I really need add a triac here for such a small current and a short pulse to latch the relay?

The answer would be yes, going by the the typical application circuit.

[image]

However, you may have another go, without a triac but with the snubber.